# I Need the Effects during Zoom in Zoomout flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects

Am working in a flex projects needs zoom in & zoom out with

more effects apart from the default effects.

please any one guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer the site [Tweenlite Effets](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) this may be useful to u